# Find states intersecting with Google maps polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a way to identify what underlying states intersect with a Google Maps polygon.  I have the ability to identify if two polygons intersect in Maps, so one non-ideal possibility would be to download state boundary data and check to see if each intersect with the polygon.  This could get time consuming checking a polygon against 50 states in every call and the more precise the state boundary, the longer this would take.  Is there a way natively with the API or a better way to determine the states that are below the polygon?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
// variables
var map;
var infoWindow;

// initialize map
initMap();

// initialize map
function initMap() {
  // map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 36.99816565700228,
      lng: -88.9013671875
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // coordinates
  var coords = [{
    lat: 37.47049847079873,
    lng: -89.82421875
  }, {
    lat: 36.760891249565624,
    lng: -90.0164794921875
  }, {
    lat: 36.25313319699069,
    lng: -88.6102294921875
  }, {
    lat: 37.583765767186236,
    lng: -87.6104736328125
  }];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  poly.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div#map {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: You could reduce the set of polygons that you need to do the complete calculation on by checking only those whose bounds intersect with your polygon.

Comment: Essentially, that's what I'm trying to find...  The ones whose bounds intersect my polygon's bounds.  How would I go about limiting my search to find just those?

Comment: [google.maps.LatLngBounds.intersects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of concept using FusionTables for the state polygons.  The resulting candidate states are:

- Arkansas
- Illinois
- Kentucky
- Missouri
- Tennessee

(Arkansas doesn't actually intersect)

```js
  google.load('visualization', '1', {
    'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
  });

  // variables
  var map, infoWindow, layer, geoXml, poly;
  var FT_TableID = '19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA'; // numeric ID 420419;
  var CountryName = "United States of America";

  // initialize map
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

  // initialize map
  function initMap() {
    // map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {
        lat: 36.99816565700228,
        lng: -88.9013671875
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // coordinates
    var coords = [{
      lat: 37.47049847079873,
      lng: -89.82421875
    }, {
      lat: 36.760891249565624,
      lng: -90.0164794921875
    }, {
      lat: 36.25313319699069,
      lng: -88.6102294921875
    }, {
      lat: 37.583765767186236,
      lng: -87.6104736328125
    }];

    // Construct the polygon.
    poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: coords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    var polybounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i=0; i<poly.getPath().getLength();i++) {
      polybounds.extend(poly.getPath().getAt(i));
    }
    poly.bounds = polybounds;

    poly.setMap(map);
    //   SELECT 'name_0', 'name_1', 'kml_4326' FROM 19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA WHERE 'name_0' = 'United States of America' ORDER by 'name_1'
    // Fusion Table data ID
    geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
      // map: map,
      zoom: false,
      infoWindow: infoWindow,
      singleInfoWindow: true
    });

    DisplayCountry(CountryName);

  }

  function DisplayCountry(CountryName) {
    var FT_Query = "SELECT 'kml_4326' FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE 'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "';";
    // var FT_Options = { suppressInfoWindows: true, query:FT_Query };
    FT_QueryObj = {
      from: FT_TableID,
      select: "kml_4326",
      where: "'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "'"
    };
    document.getElementById("FTquery").innerHTML = FT_Query + "<br>select:" + FT_QueryObj.select + "<br>from:" + FT_QueryObj.from + "<br>where:" + FT_QueryObj.where;
    var FT_Options = {
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      query: FT_QueryObj
    };


    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_Options);
    layer.setMap(map);

    FT_Query = "SELECT 'kml_4326' FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE 'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "';";
    gpolygons = [];
    FT_QueryObj = {
      select: 'kml_4326',
      from: FT_TableID,
      where: "name_0 = '" + CountryName + "'"
    };
    layer.setQuery(FT_QueryObj);
    document.getElementById("FTquery").innerHTML = FT_Query + "<br>select:" + FT_QueryObj.select + "<br>from:" + FT_QueryObj.from + "<br>where:" + FT_QueryObj.where;
    var FT_Query2 = "SELECT 'name_0', 'name_1', 'kml_4326' FROM " + FT_TableID + " WHERE 'name_0' = '" + CountryName + "' ORDER by 'name_1'";
    document.getElementById("FTquery2").innerHTML = FT_Query2;
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query2);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

    //set the callback function
    query.send(getData);
  }

  //define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
  function getData(response) {
    if (!response) {
      alert('no response');
      return;
    }
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }
    FTresponse = response;
    //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
    //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
    numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
    if (numRows <= 1) {
      document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = "no data";
      return;
    }

    //concatenate the results into a string, you can build a table here
    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var name = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1);
      var kml = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2);
      geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>" + kml + "</Placemark>");
      var firstResults = [];
      gpolygons[name] = geoXml.docs[geoXml.docs.length-1].gpolygons[0];
      if (gpolygons[name].bounds.intersects(poly.bounds)) {
      document.getElementById('intersects').innerHTML += name+"<br>";
      firstResults[name] = gpolygons[name];
      }
    }
    //display the results on the page


  }
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div#map {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="intersects"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="FTquery"></div>
<div id="FTquery2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!